# How can I make the execvp function execute each command line argument?

Tags: c, ubuntu, unix, exec, execvp

I'm trying to write a program that takes multiple command line arguments from the same line of input (e.g. /bin/uname /bin/date) before executing them and indicating that the process has completed successfully. When I use an infinite loop the program prints each execution out perfectly, however the question stipulates that the parent process must terminate after all of the children terminate. Attempting to make this happen leads to only one process completing, despite the fact that their is a for loop that should allow it to repeat. Any help telling me how I should go about it would be awesome.

I have tried moving the for loop to various different locations, as well as remove exit calls to try and make it successfully loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define KGRN "\x1B[32m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{ 
    int counter;
    int status;
    int COMMAND_LINE_SIZE = 64;
    char command[COMMAND_LINE_SIZE];

    pid_t pid;

    printf("$ ");
    scanf("%s", command);//read a line from user and store it in array command
    printf("\n");

    for(counter=0;counter<argc;counter++){
        if ((pid = fork()) <  0) {
            perror("forking child process failed\n");
            exit(1); 
        }

        if (pid==0){ // child
            char *argv[] = {command, NULL};
            execvp(argv[counter], argv);
            exit(0);
        }
        //in parent
        pid = wait(&status);
        if(WIFEXITED(status) == 1)
            printf(KGRN "Command %s has completed successfully\n" RESET, command);
        else
            printf("failure\n");
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
$ /bin/uname /bin/date /bin/ls
Linux  
Command /bin/uname has completed successfully
$ 
Sun Sep 15 12:24:39 UTC 2019
Command /bin/date has completed successfully
$ 
a.out  new.c  q3.c  trial.c
Command /bin/ls has completed successfully
```

Current output:

```
$ /bin/ls /bin/uname

a.out  new.c  q3.c  trial.c
Command /bin/ls has completed successfully
```

Comment: The parent `fork()`s (potentially) multiple children, but it `wait()`s only once.  If you want it to collect multiple children then it must `wait()` for each.

Comment: @JohnBollinger does that mean adding it to the for loop or is that not that case? How would I go about ensuring that happens?

Comment: Also, it appears that you `execvp(argv[0])`, but you probably don't want to do that.  It would normally run a new instance of the parent process, thus creating a lightweight fork bomb.

Comment: You need to do the childish action in the fork loop (use `execvp()`), and then wait in a `waitpid()` loop for all children to die.

Comment: If the parent `wait()`s in the same loop in which it `fork()`s, then you will collect each child before forking the next.  That's fine, if it's what you want.  If you want to afford the children the opportunity to run concurrently, however, then you must instead use a second, separate loop to collect the children.

Comment: Why are you reading from standard input? You’re supposed to be executing the commands in the arguments.

Comment: @JohnBollinger would you have any sort of examples regarding the two loops allowing concurrency, that is my end goal.

Comment: Why are you replacing `argv` by a new variable and using `argc` knowing that the second `argv` contain only `1` element besides the `NULL` but the `counter` can be greater because it takes the value of `argc`. That can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @XBlueCode i'm slightly confused by that, could you suggest something i can do to ensure i dont have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but there are a number of problems, many of them pointed out in the comments to the question:

- You re-execute `argv[0]` — the program — which bodes ill.
- You should normally execute the child's action in the loop that forks the children.
- If you want the children executing concurrently, you need the `wait()` call outside the loop that forks them.
- You read a command from standard input even though the specification says to execute the command line arguments.
- You use the data that was read from standard input as the command name for the executed process, rather than the command line argument.
- You have a local variable `argv` shadowing (hiding) the `argv` argument to `main()`.  Thus, the code in the `execvp()` is accessing out of bounds of the `argv` array after `counter` reaches 2, and you use a null pointer when `counter` is 1.
- You should not report success (`exit(0);`) after a child fails to execute.
- I think you should report on which process failed to execute — to standard error, of course — when the child fails to execute.

Incidentally, your sample command lines all use the full path to the command, making the use of `execvp()` unnecessary.  You could perfectly well type just the name of the command, like you would at the shell prompt, and then `execvp()` would find the command and run it (see my example runs).

#### Asynchronous execution

Fixing those and adding a few minor tweaks, and running the command line arguments asynchronously (possibly many commands running at the same time) yields code like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid <  0)
        {
            perror("forking child process failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) // child
        {
            char *args[] = { argv[counter], NULL };
            execvp(args[0], args);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s: (%d) %s\n",
                    argv[0], argv[counter], errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    int failed = 0;
    while ((corpse = waitpid(0, &status, 0)) > 0)
    {
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            printf("Process %d exited with status %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                   corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status), status);
            if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
                failed++;
        }
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            printf("Process %d was signalled %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                   corpse, WTERMSIG(status), status);
            failed++;
        }
    }
    return((failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The `failed` variable tracks whether any of the commands failed, and the process only reports success (exits with 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS) if every one of the commands succeeded; otherwise, it exits with a failure indication (exits with EXIT_FAILURE, which is usually 1).
When run on my Mac (as `args41` created from `args41.c`), it produced:

```
$ args41 uname date ls
Sun Sep 15 07:26:58 MDT 2019
Darwin
Process 1907 exited with status 0 (0x0000)
Process 1908 exited with status 0 (0x0000)
20000-leagues-under-the-sea.txt bin                             maxargs.sh
LICENSE.md                      conn11                          overlap.data
Metriseis_2012.dat              conn11.c                        overlap47.c
README.md                       conn11.dSYM                     overlap61.c
Safe                            conn13                          overlap73
Untracked                       conn13.c                        overlap73.c
acr.list                        conn13.dSYM                     overlap73.dSYM
acronym29.c                     conn17                          packages
acronym43                       conn17.c                        pseudo-json.md
acronym43.c                     conn17.dSYM                     question.md
acronym43.dSYM                  conn29                          sll43.c
acronym47                       conn29.c                        so-0167-2112
acronym47.c                     conn29.dSYM                     so-0167-2112.c
acronym47.dSYM                  doc                             so-0167-2112.dSYM
acronym53                       dr41                            so-1043-1305
acronym53.c                     dr41.c                          so-4921-8019
acronym53.dSYM                  dr41.dSYM                       so-4970-8730
acronym59                       dw41                            so-4971-1989
acronym59.c                     dw41.c                          so-4985-0919
acronym59.dSYM                  dw41.dSYM                       so-5102-0102
argc37                          etc                             so-5134-1743
argc37.c                        gccw67                          so-5225-1783
argc37.dSYM                     gccw67.c                        so-5279-4924
args41                          gccw67.dSYM                     so-5358-5962
args41.c                        gccw67.o                        so-5394-5215
args41.dSYM                     get.jl.activity                 so-5416-6308
argv89                          inc                             so-5424-4465.md
argv89.c                        lib                             src
argv89.dSYM                     makefile
Process 1909 exited with status 0 (0x0000)
$ args41 many things to do
args41: failed to execute many: (2) No such file or directory
args41: failed to execute things: (2) No such file or directory
args41: failed to execute to: (2) No such file or directory
args41: failed to execute do: (2) No such file or directory
Process 1939 exited with status 1 (0x0100)
Process 1941 exited with status 1 (0x0100)
Process 1940 exited with status 1 (0x0100)
Process 1942 exited with status 1 (0x0100)
$
```

Clearly, if you want the processes run synchronously, you should place the `waitpid()` loop inside the `for` loop.  You should still use a loop because a process can inherit children it didn't fork in obscure circumstances.  You might prefer to use `waitpid(pid, &status, 0)` in this case; then you don't need the loop around `waitpid()`.

If you want to track process names and yet run the processes asynchronously, then the parent process woul need to keep a record of the PID of each child in an array as they're forked off, and the reporting loop would search through the list of known children to report which one died.

#### Synchronous execution

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int failed = 0;

    for (int counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid <  0)
        {
            perror("forking child process failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) // child
        {
            char *args[] = { argv[counter], NULL };
            execvp(args[0], args);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s: (%d) %s\n",
                    argv[0], argv[counter], errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            int status;
            if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to wait for %s process %d: (%d) %s\n",
                        argv[counter], (int)pid, errno, strerror(errno));
                failed++;
            }
            else if (WIFEXITED(status))
            {
                printf("Process %s exited with status %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                        argv[counter], WEXITSTATUS(status), status);
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
                    failed++;
            }
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            {
                printf("Process %s was signalled %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                        argv[counter], WTERMSIG(status), status);
                failed++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Process %s died unexpectedly (0x%.4X)\n",
                        argv[counter], status);
                failed++;
            }
        }
    }

    return((failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Example output (`args89` created from `args89.c`):

```
$ args89 date uname ls
Sun Sep 15 08:34:00 MDT 2019
Process date exited with status 0 (0x0000)
Darwin
Process uname exited with status 0 (0x0000)
20000-leagues-under-the-sea.txt argv89.c                        makefile
LICENSE.md                      argv89.dSYM                     maxargs.sh
Metriseis_2012.dat              bin                             overlap.data
README.md                       conn11                          overlap47.c
Safe                            conn11.c                        overlap61.c
Untracked                       conn11.dSYM                     overlap73
acr.list                        conn13                          overlap73.c
acronym29.c                     conn13.c                        overlap73.dSYM
acronym43                       conn13.dSYM                     packages
acronym43.c                     conn17                          pseudo-json.md
acronym43.dSYM                  conn17.c                        question.md
acronym47                       conn17.dSYM                     sll43.c
acronym47.c                     conn29                          so-0167-2112
acronym47.dSYM                  conn29.c                        so-0167-2112.c
acronym53                       conn29.dSYM                     so-0167-2112.dSYM
acronym53.c                     doc                             so-1043-1305
acronym53.dSYM                  dr41                            so-4921-8019
acronym59                       dr41.c                          so-4970-8730
acronym59.c                     dr41.dSYM                       so-4971-1989
acronym59.dSYM                  dw41                            so-4985-0919
argc37                          dw41.c                          so-5102-0102
argc37.c                        dw41.dSYM                       so-5134-1743
argc37.dSYM                     etc                             so-5225-1783
args41                          gccw67                          so-5279-4924
args41.c                        gccw67.c                        so-5358-5962
args41.dSYM                     gccw67.dSYM                     so-5394-5215
args89                          gccw67.o                        so-5416-6308
args89.c                        get.jl.activity                 so-5424-4465.md
args89.dSYM                     inc                             src
argv89                          lib
Process ls exited with status 0 (0x0000)
$
```

#### Asynchronous execution with process name tracking

This variant runs the commands asynchronously but also tracks which process belonged to each PID.  Note that it uses a function (shock, horror) to determine the argument that corresponds to the PID that just died.  The array is set up so that it is easy to track numbers — the element 0 of the array of PIDs is not used.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int find_pid(int pid, int num_pids, pid_t pids[num_pids])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < num_pids; i++)
    {
        if (pids[i] == pid)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pids[argc];
    for (int counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid <  0)
        {
            perror("forking child process failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) // child
        {
            char *args[] = { argv[counter], NULL };
            execvp(args[0], args);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s: (%d) %s\n",
                    argv[0], argv[counter], errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            pids[counter] = pid;
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    int failed = 0;
    while ((corpse = waitpid(0, &status, 0)) > 0)
    {
        int index = find_pid(corpse, argc, pids);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                    corpse, status);
            failed++;
        }
        else if (WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            printf("Process %s (PID %d) exited with status %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                   argv[index], corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status), status);
            if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
                failed++;
        }
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            printf("Process %s (PID %d) was signalled %d (0x%.4X)\n",
                   argv[index], corpse, WTERMSIG(status), status);
            failed++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Process %s (PID %d) died from indeterminate causes (0x%.4X)\n",
                   argv[index], corpse, status);
            failed++;
        }
    }
    return((failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Example run (`args79` created from `args79.c`):

```
$ args79 uname date pwd
/Users/jleffler/soq
Process pwd (PID 2105) exited with status 0 (0x0000)
Darwin
Sun Sep 15 09:04:37 MDT 2019
Process uname (PID 2103) exited with status 0 (0x0000)
Process date (PID 2104) exited with status 0 (0x0000)
$
```

Comment: Hi Jonathon, thanks for making this clearer to me! I just got one more thing in regard to achieving concurrency? I placed the while loop into the for loop and it only allowed for one command line argument to work?

Comment: See my latest version — you've got both asynchronous code (with the waiting done outside the loop that launches the child processes) and synchronous code (with the waiting done inside the loop that launches the child processes).  The asynchronous code achieves concurrency; the synchronous code does not. I'm not sure whether that's what you saw before you typed your comment — I assume you didn't see the update since it seems to cover both cases you might need.

Comment: in order to say something like "/bin/ls completed successfully" would i not need to add back the command array i was utilising in my prior build, or is there some sort of call i can use to print the name of the argument?

Comment: See the args79 example in my updated answer.  Any further variations are for you to explore on your own, or in a new question.